# re enter USA with B1/B2 visa

Tags: visas, usa, b1-b2-visas

I had visited USA 5 years ago, my B1/B2 visa expires in 2020, I got the visa while I was working for my former company which I quit 3 years ago. Since my visa is still valid, so I guess I have no visa issues. And now I would like to re-enter a week later for my vacation. I have couple of questions, please someone clarify

I have been wandering, I have travel itinerary, valid passport, b1/b2 visa, I booked a hotel for 4 weeks but I don't no anybody (personal contacts) in USA.

Do I need to have somebody contact information to enter USA?

Does the immigration officer at airport request USA citizen contacts?

Answer (score 2):

If you're staying in a hotel all that they care about is the details of where you're staying.

There are quite a few people that come to this country that may have no US citizen contacts so the citizenship status of the person doesn't matter.  The things that do matter are:

- Where are you going?
- Where are you staying?
- Do you have sufficient funds for the journey?
- Do you have medical insurance to cover you in case of emergency? (if I am not mistaken)

And the most important:

- When and whether are you leaving?

Your contacts unless they are on some watch lists may not matter as much.

Comment: Hi Karlson, Thanks for the useful info.  Do I really have to demonstrate funds? Is this medical insurance necessary to enter USA? please let me know if so I can  get these docs in advance.

Comment: @VijaySaradhi It is possible: https://help.cbp.gov/app/answers/detail/a_id/796/~/foreign-visitor-having-to-carry-a-certain-amount-of-money-to-enter-the-u.s.